# Makefile rule for "depends on header file if present"

Tags: makefile

I have a directory in which about half of the .c files have corresponding .h files, but the others do not.

How would I write a makefile rule to transform a .c to a .o, such that the .o depends on the .c file AND depends on the .h if the .h file is present?  Or would I write two separate rules for this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it works to have two rules: one for .o targets that have .h counterparts and one for those that don't:

```
%.o : %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $@

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $@
```

Comment: The documentation for GNU `make` [specifies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) that this approach will indeed work with that `make` implementation.  Note well, however, that pattern rules such as those are a GNU-specific feature.  There are other `make` implementations, and I'm not aware of any that provide GNU compatibility in this area.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: thank you.  If you know of a cross-platform compatible approach that accomplishes the same thing, please chime in!